# MongoDB Text Search

Tags: mongodb

I see that we can limit the number of items scanned in mongodb text search using the method mentioned in this document : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/limit-number-of-items-scanned-for-text-search/

Let me write here in brief. I have a collection of inventory documents:

```
{ _id: 1, dept: "tech", description: "lime green computer" }
{ _id: 2, dept: "tech", description: "wireless red mouse" }
{ _id: 3, dept: "kitchen", description: "green placemat" }
{ _id: 4, dept: "kitchen", description: "red peeler" }
{ _id: 5, dept: "food", description: "green apple" }
{ _id: 6, dept: "food", description: "red potato" }
```

Then I created an index :

```
db.inventory.ensureIndex(
   {
     dept: 1,
     description: "text"
   }
)
```

I can write this query and it works :

```
db.inventory.find( { dept: "kitchen", $text: { $search: "green" } } )
```

Now, if I use this approach, I can search in a specific department. My problem is, I want this feature, but I also want the freedom to search in all department. But this query doesn't work : `db.inventory.find( { $text: { $search: "green" } } )`

I am using version 2.6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index you created is a compound one, so that is no way to run `db.inventory.find( { $text: { $search: "green" } } )`.

If you want to run both, you can change the index as

```
db.inventory.ensureIndex(
   {
     description: "text",
     dept: 1
   }
)
```

But there will be more scanning on the first query.